# Displaying the buy/sell volume ratio for each order block

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to update LuxAlgo open-source SMC script: https://www.tradingview.com/script/CnB3fSph-Smart-Money-Concepts-LuxAlgo/
I want to add a logic of displaying the buy/sell volume per order block as you can see from the screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyJiY.jpg

I'm looking to display for all the visible order blocks the volume per order block + the volume percentage for each order block compared to the volume total

Here's what I did so far: https://privatebin.net/?f6b94a9f8a00febf#7HJBxN65PWwVRrF2nL4EiaeUNvw47HF7prjYA88rsge3

I created the display_ob_volume() function called whenever a new OB is displayed

It's not working at all as I struggle to split vertically in two each order block so as to show the buy/sell volume within each block